# Открыть все папки, а затем и все файлы в этих папках Python

Tags: python

Есть папка, в ней лежит еще например 10 папок с названием от "0" до "9". В свою очередь в каждой из этих папок лежит по 10 аудиофайлов. В конечном итоге я бы хотел открыть все считать все аудиофайлы и извлечь для них признаки таким образом, чтобы все аудиофайлы назывались по названию их соответствующих папок.

```
import os
import numpy as np
path = "C:\\Users\\ss\\Desktop\\NN"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    foldername = path + "\\" + filename
    print(foldername)
```

Таким образом я получаю список папок внутри основной папки:
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\0
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\1
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\2
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\3
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\4
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\5
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\6
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\7
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\8
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\9
C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\Test

Начнем с того, как мне все эти строки с названием папок преобразовать в массив или список из названий:?

Comment: Приведите пример своего решения, и мы подскажем, в чем ваша ошибка и как ее устранить.

Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: По-моему подобные вопросы уже 100500 раз задавали и на них есть ответы

Comment: Сортировать музыку - хорошее дело, но, действительно, вопрос поставлен плохо. Для выбора всех файлов юзайте `os.walk('your directories')`, а для создания директорий и перемещения `os.mkdir` и `os. rename` (`os.replace`), а либы для получения метатегов из аудиофайлов можно загуглить. Также учтите, что далеко не во всех аудиофайлах нормально проставлены метатеги.

Comment: Начнём с того - что вы уже прочитали про массивы и работу с ними? Совершенно ничего, верно? Так сначала почитайте, а после это вероятно и вопрос отпадёт.

Answer (score 1):

**Если я вас правильно понял - вам нужно это:**

```
import os

array = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\ss\\Desktop\\NN') # получаем список папок из \NN

for i in range(len(array)): # в цикле от первой до последней папки
    path = f'C:\\Users\\ss\\Desktop\\NN\\{array[i]}' # получаем директорию i-ой папки
    os.chdir(path) # перемещаемся в директорию i-ой папки
    path_files = os.listdir(path) # получаем список файлов i-ой папки

    for g in range(len(path_files)): # цикле от первого до последнего файла i-ой папки
        os.rename(path_files[g], f'Файл номер {g+1} из {i} папки.mp3') # переименовываем g-ый файл в "Файл номер {g+1} из {i} папки.mp3"
```

**Здесь:**

**`array[i]` - имя папки, `i` - номер папки;**

**`path_files[g]` - имя файла, `g` - номер файла.**

Вместо `f'Файл номер {g+1} из {i} папки.mp3')` подставьте нужное вам имя для файла.

---

**Результат работы алгоритма:**

Содержимое `C:\Users\ss\Desktop\NN\0\`

Получаем:

`a.mp3` `b.mp3` `c.mp3`

Вывод:

`Файл номер 1 из 0 папки.mp3` `Файл номер 2 из 0 папки.mp3` `Файл номер 3 из 0 папки.mp3`

---

Информация по работе с модулем `os`: [ссылка](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html)